# resizeevent is not firing

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I am using meteor-google-map. I am trying to resize the map like this `google.map.event.trigger(GoogleMaps.maps.exampleMap , resize)` but the problem is it's not working. My map is hidden in a tab so whenever I open that tab the map does not shows. I tried using the resize function but that is also not doing anything. Can anybody tell me why it is not displaying

**CODE ADDED**

> map HTML

```
<body>
<div class="row">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#what">What</a></li>
  <li><a href="#where">Where</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="what" class="col s12">
</div>
 <div id="where" class="col s12">
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="exampleMap" options=exampleMapOptions}}
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

> map.js

```
Template.body.helpers({
  exampleMapOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.body.onCreated(function() {
  // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
  GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
    // Add a marker to the map once it's ready
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.options.center,
      map: map.instance
    });
  });
});
Template.body.event({
   'click .where a':function(){
    debugger;
    google.maps.event.trigger(GoogleMaps.maps.exampleMap , 'resize');
  }
});
```

When the page loads the what tab is open. When user clicks on where link inside the li the where tab opens. The first time it open I cannot see the map but after resizing the browser the map loads. I tried to trigger the resize event myself but that didn't work out either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your not passing in the correct instance that the maps lib requires

```
google.maps.event.trigger(GoogleMaps.maps.exampleMap.instance , 'resize')
```

Comment: can you tell me one thing that why isn't the google map working on mobile. I do not get any map it's a whole blank div. Here is an image 

http://i.imgur.com/8Yln0bnl.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code is using `google.map.event`.  However the Google Maps namespace is `maps` not `map`.  i.e. it should be `google.maps.event`

Secondly, when you call `trigger` you need to pass the name of the event as a string, i.e. `google.maps.event.trigger(GoogleMaps.maps.exampleMap , 'resize')`.

See:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: I am using meteor-google-map. I wrote it but I may accidently cut that part. I have tried editing the question but I can't do it

Comment: There's nothing in the tiny bit of code in your question that's using Meteor; it's all just standard Google Maps API code.   You should update your question with more code that fully demonstrates what you're doing, enough so that we could replicate the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: any idea why I am facing this problem ?